# CXF directory must be set in global preferences SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, cxf, webservices-client

I'm using IntelliJ on Mac OS to create the stub from SOAP UI. After entering the WSDL url, output directory as "/Users/kaushik/Desktop" and package, when I try to generate the stub, it displays an error in a dialog box "CXF directory must be set in global preferences".
I've tested the requests and it's working.

[image: Error dialog while trying to generate.]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it after I put the stubs in the client in the same package(com.abc.controller) as the one where I had my service class in the web service.

Hope this will be helpful for all facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

On the code generation screen (Apache CXF Stub) you need to specify CXF binaries location - click "Tools" (on the bottom right) and then in "Global Properties" set path to CXF (to the \bin folder).

[image]